# How can I catch specific add and update cache events in Redis using Jedis?

Tags: redis, jedis

Specific NEW and UPDATE cache event on REDIS CACHE KEYSPACE NOTIFICATION.

Hi there,
I am trying to catch 2 keyspace event "a New key event" and "update value of key event" in redis cache, im using Jedis,
My problem is when i catch new key event always has a set value event go with this.

```
2023-05-29 09:43:06.938  INFO 22040 --- [ddedContainer-1] c.e.g.C.RedisCacheEventHandleConfig      : Received task event: 1tuanAnh1 for channel: __keyevent@0__:new
2023-05-29 09:43:06.938  INFO 22040 --- [ddedContainer-1] c.e.g.C.RedisCacheEventHandleConfig      : HANDLING NEW CACHE EVENT!!!
2023-05-29 09:43:06.938  INFO 22040 --- [ddedContainer-1] c.e.g.Service.CacheHandleServiceImpl     : Key add: 1tuanAnh1
2023-05-29 09:43:06.938  INFO 22040 --- [dateContainer-1] c.e.g.C.RedisCacheEventHandleConfig      : Received task event: 1tuanAnh1 for channel: __keyevent@0__:set
2023-05-29 09:43:06.941  INFO 22040 --- [dateContainer-1] c.e.g.C.RedisCacheEventHandleConfig      : HANDLING UPDATE CACHE EVENT!!!
2023-05-29 09:43:06.941  INFO 22040 --- [dateContainer-1] c.e.g.Service.CacheHandleServiceImpl     : Key update: 1tuanAnh1
```

this is my code:

```
public class RedisCacheEventHandleConfig implements MessageListener {
    private final CacheHandleService cacheHandleService;
    private final Gson gson;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        String key = new String(message.getBody());
        String channel = new String(message.getChannel());
        log.info("Received task event: {} for channel: {}", key, channel);
        switch (channel) {
            case "__keyevent@0__:new":
                log.info("HANDLING NEW CACHE EVENT!!!");
                cacheHandleService.handleAddCacheForKey(key);
                break;
            case "__keyevent@0__:set":
                Jedis jedis = new Jedis("http://localhost:6379");
                DataExample res = gson.fromJson(jedis.get(key), DataExample.class);
                if (res != null){
                    log.info("HANDLING UPDATE CACHE EVENT!!!");
                    cacheHandleService.handleUpdateCacheForKey(key);
                }
                break;
            case "__keyevent@0__:expired":
                log.info("HANDLING EXPIRED CACHE EVENT!!!");
                cacheHandleService.handleExpiredCacheForKey(key);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class CacheHandleServiceImpl implements CacheHandleService{
    @Override
    public void handleAddCacheForKey(String key) {
        log.info("Key add: {}", key);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleUpdateCacheForKey(String key) {
        log.info("Key update: {}", key);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleExpiredCacheForKey(String key) {
        log.info("Key expired: {}", key);
    }
}
```

How can i catch specific add cache event and update cache event in redis ?
Thanks for reading.

Iam following this doc: https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is when i catch new key event always has a set value event go with this.

That's by Redis design. You can simply choose any one option to use and ignore the other one. For example, in your code you can remove either `case "__keyevent@0__:new":` block or `case "__keyevent@0__:set":` block.

Also, the doc says, *"**>= 7.0**: Event type **new** added"*. So you may as well consider a Redis version lower than 7.0.

> How can i catch specific add cache event and update cache event in redis ?

Are you interested in all possible add and update events? Or events of only [Strings](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/strings/) data structure is enough for you? [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set/) command does both add and update operations in Strings. So you can choose to use only that command (in your code that is the `case "__keyevent@0__:set":` block).

Comment: thank you sir for answer my question, I already have a solution for this problem. I expired immediately a key which updated and catch that expired event for handle process. But again, thank for yor support.